# Vscode - Editor accepting suggestions on typing parenthesis

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Just upgraded to vscode 1.25 and now when suggestions show up, if I type `(` it accepts the suggestion. Is this new? How do I remove this?

Comment: mine also accepts for `,` so when creating anonymous functions it fills it in, but this has been happening for a while not just the new version

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you just need to add this to your settings:

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false
```

and make sure this is `on` so enter/tab still works

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on"
```

Comment: This is a workaround, not a solution, since I actually like it when . or ( or tab accepts the selected suggestion; the problem is that the first suggestion is automatically selected even when the typer doesn't press down-arrow to select it. See my bug report (and thumbs-up it if you agree) : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/67698